# Misbehaving Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been using the RegEx `/[ -~]/i` in JavaScript for a while now and found that it works well testing for **any** ASCII character including the space. Today I accidentally used `/^[ -~]$/i` and found much to my surprise that `/^[ -~]$/i.test('Stackoverflow is great')` failed owing to the space character.  My understanding of Regexes is rather limited but even so I fail to see what I might be doing wrong here. Perhaps somone here can shed some light on what is happening?

Comment: The anchors will make it match the complete string, without it only checks if **contains** a part matching the regex

Comment: @Tushar why would those anchors stop `Stackoverflow is great` from being matched?

Comment: Because ^ is beginning of the string and $ is the end. So your regex matches a string with exactly one character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss a quantifier, a `+` or `*`:

```js
alert(/^[ -~]*$/i.test('Stackoverflow is great'));
```

Without the quantifier a character class just matches **1** symbol. You need that quantifier in this case because you added anchors that require matching at the beginning of the string (`^`) and at the string end (`$`).

Note that `*` means *match 0 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern*, and `+` matches 1 or more occurrences.

And it is true as for what your regex matches as the hyphen creates a range between a space and a tilde:

[image]

Comment: Just one thing that I missed when answering: you do not need `/i` modifier as you already match both upper- and lowercase Latin letters with that range.